# Why I can't invoke function inside of another function in JS, if functions are objects?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I can invoke function inside the object, but I can't invoke function inside the function.
How it really works?

```
const baz = {
    bar() { console.log('hi');}
}

baz.bar(); // -> hi

function foo() {
    function bar() {
        console.log('there');
    }
}

console.log(foo.bar); // undefined, why???
```

Comment: Why should that work? `foo` is not an object

Comment: @NicoHaase - Functions are objects in JavaScript.

Comment: you need to do: `foo.bar = function() {console.log('there')}`

Comment: `bar` is not a *property* of `foo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in your second example, `foo` has no `bar` property on it, but `foo.bar` looks for a property called `bar` on the `foo` object. If your question comes from the fact both of your examples use `{}`, then: in JavaScript `{}` are used for a least a couple of different things:

1. Delimiting an object literal, as in your first example
2. Delimiting the body of a function, as in your second example, or  a block (for instance, the block attached to an `if` or `for` or similar)

Those are completely unrelated things, they just look somewhat similar. *(There are other things `{}` are used for, such as indicating named imports [`import { x } from "y"`], object destructuring [though really that's just the converse of #1 above], probably others...)*

Also note that with your code, a `bar` function is only created *if* and *when* you call `foo`, and a different `bar` function is created every time you call `foo`.

You *can* assign a function to a property on another function, though, just not that way. For instance:

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("foo");
}
foo.bar = function() {
    console.log("bar");
};
foo.bar(); // "bar"
foo();     // "foo"
```

That works because, as you said, functions are objects, so you can add properties to them.

If you want a more similar declarative syntax, you can create an object with the functions and copy them to the target function via [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
// Object.assign copies properties from the second argument onward
// onto the object in the first argument
const foo = Object.assign(
    // Function expression, creates a function:
    function foo() {
        console.log("foo");
    },
    // Object literal, creates an object:
    {
        bar() {
            console.log("bar");
        }
    }
);
foo.bar(); // "bar"
foo();     // "foo"
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer! It's interesting, that when I want to look at foo from your second snippet it shows without bar function, but when I'm asking for foo.bar, I can find it.
`console.log(foo); // ƒ () { console.log("foo");} // without bar
console.log(foo.bar); // ƒ bar() { console.log("bar");}`

Comment: @ForceAwakenz - My pleasure! Re not seeing the `bar` property: It depends on what tool you're using to look at it. For instance, the devtools in Chrome (and related) browsers just show a cursive *f* followed by the string representation of the function, which is just its source code, not its other properties (this is also what you get from `foo.toString()`), but Firefox's devtools show it to you with all of its properties (including `bar`, `name`, `length`, ...). So it's just what you're using to look at it. There's nothing unusual about the `bar` property. Happy coding!

Comment: (Heh, overlapping comments -- apparently you're using Chrome or related. :-) )